# Xcode 13 - Missing IOS 15 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've just installed Xcode 13 - primarily to test some functionality on IOS 15.

However I noticed that IOS 15 is missing from the simulator list.

[image]

Guessing i'm missing a way to add an ios 15 simulator - wonder if anyone can offer any advice please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That window is for *downloading* simulators (for *past* SDKs). You already *have* all the *current* iOS 15 simulators, listed in the Devices and Simulators window. Just switch to the Simulators pane in that window and have at it. Start by asking to create a simulator for a recent device, such as an iPhone 13; it is an iOS 15 simulator.

Comment: I was led to the same path by accessing the devices & simulators window but having selected the iPhone 5, which had support only up to iOS 12.4. When I changed the device to any of the latest ones, I could see I had the option to spawn a new sim with iOS 15.  Living & learning.

Comment: As of today, October 29th, 2021, I don't see iOS 15.1 simulator in either place.

Comment: @Dave You've downloaded the new Xcode beta, have you? Anyway your remark is irrelevant to the question actually posed.

Comment: I have already used the 13.1 Xcode but still does not show the IOS 15 simulator.

Comment: Same issue, the iOS15 simulator was there and out of the blue it is missing

Comment: Also missing iOS 15 sims and download in XC14.2 Jan 2023. Even selecting a device that clearly came with 15 such as iPhone 13, not available only iOS 16.

Comment: @ChrisPaveglio The question (and my answer) are about Xcode 13. For Xcode 14 obviously you would have to download an iOS 15 SDK. The iOS SDKs are not "missing" for download. You have a choice of four of them, in fact.

Comment: Oh the other downloads are now inside a "+" button, I remembered them all being listed on the main "platforms" view before.

Comment: @ChrisPaveglio Programmers are nimble, they adapt to change :)

Answer (score 4):

I faced an issue that suddenly all my simulators are gone without a reason and if I check Xcode I saw no simulators as the below image

[image: No Similators found]

If I go into Window > Devices & Simulators, It is empty

[image]

I figured out the problem, it was that Xcode deleted simulators entries and I have to add them in again from Window > Devices & Simulators from the + button on the bottom left corner

After that, it is again on the list of simulators

[image]